# Rails ActiveRecord Wildcard + Interpolation Issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have been tried the following query and it succeeds (only returns the one record with exact match):

```
def self.search(query)
    where("name like ?", query)
end
```

SQL Executed:

```
SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (name LIKE 'Game')
```

This query also succeeds (It returns multiple records and there are multiple records with the words 'Game' in their name):

```
def self.search(query)
    where("name like ?", "%Game%")
end
```

SQL Executed:

```
SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (name like '%Game%')
```

However when I attempt place a wildcard character with interpolation:

```
def self.search(query)
    where("name like ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

SQL Executed:

```
SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE (name like '%[\"Game\"]%')
```

It doesn't return anything.  Knowing me...probably missing a comma or something.  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Look at the development log to see what SQL is being generated.

Comment: Thanks Mark...I updated the post to include those as well...

Comment: What's `query` actually contain, and what's its type? Are you sure it's a single string?

Comment: I submit exactly the same string (the word 'Game') in the first case as in the third case.  From the SQL statements it seems as though 'query' contains the correct string.

Comment: From the SQL it seems as though it tries to find '%[\"Game\"]%'.  I don't know where the square brackets and escaped quotation marks come from.

Comment: Found the answer...thanks for the tip Dave!  The extra bracket was being passed in from an earlier method.

Comment: @schmudu No problem--I learned early to always check my assumptions! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an Array instead of a String.

Try:

```
def self.search(query)
  where("name like ?", "%#{query[0]}%") unless query.empty?
end
```

If it succeeds then fix the query input to be sent as string and not an Array.

Comment: Hey negamil, an earlier comment from Dave helped me out.  Turns out an earlier method was placing some extra brackets.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Does this still protect against SQL injection?